# JS code not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, drupal-7

Trying to debug this, but it is just beyond me. I'm programming a schedule for school, using the jQuery to `append()` HTML to td's generated by the [Calendar Drupal module](https://www.drupal.org/project/calendar).

- There are tests, investigations, and lessons.
- Test every 5 lessons and an investigation every 10.
- On Monday's, Wednesday's and Friday's, you get two "things" (Two lessons, a test or an investigation, a lesson and a test, or an investigation and a lesson)
- On Tuesday And Thursday, you only get one lesson, test, or investigation
- It doesn't start at lesson 1, test 1, or inv 1, but rather at lesson 72, test 14, and investigation 8.

Here is my code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  /* Schedule */

  last = "lesson";
  lesson = 71;
  test = 13;
  inv = 7;

  function m10() {
    if (lesson % 10 == 0) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  function m5() {
    if (lesson % 5 == 0) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  function pMath1() {
    if (m10() == false && last !== "test") {

      lesson++;
      last = "lesson";
      return "Lesson " + lesson;

    } else if (m5() == true && last !== "test") {

      test++;
      last = "test";
      return "Test " + test;

    } else if (m10() == true && last == "test") {

      inv++;
      last = "inv";
      return "Inv " + inv;

    } else {
      console.log("pMath1 doesn't work");
    }
  }


  function pMath2() {
    if (m10() == false) {

      lesson++;
      last = "lesson";
      return "Lesson " + lesson;

    } else if (m5() == true && last !== "test") {

      test++;
      last = "test";
      return "Test " + test;

    } else if (m10() == true && last == "test") {

      inv++;
      last = "inv";
      return "Inv " + inv;

    } else {
      console.log("pMath2 doesn't work");
    }
  }

  $(".view-id-school .single-day td:gt(6)").each(function() {

    var datePrep = $(this).attr("data-date");
    var dateSplit = datePrep.split("-");
    var dateStr = new Date(dateSplit[0], dateSplit[1], dateSplit[2]);
    var dateStr2 = new Date(2016, 12, 03);

    var classN = $(this).attr("headers");

    if (classN == "Monday" || classN == "Wednesday" || classN == "Friday") {

      $(this).removeClass("no-entry");

      var mathC = "M: " + pMath1() + ", " + pMath2();

    } else if (classN == "Tuesday" || classN == "Thursday") {

      $(this).removeClass("no-entry");

      var mathC = "M: " + pMath1();

    } else {
      mathC = "";
    };

    content = mathC;

    if (dateStr > dateStr2) {
      $(this).find(".inner").empty().append('<div class="calendar monthview"><div class="views-field views-field-title"><span class="field-content">' + content + '</span></div><div class="cutoff" /></div></div></div>');
    }
  });


});
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/839838qm/1)

**Update**: The problem is that pMath1() always returns "Inv 8" and pMath2 () remains undefined

**Update 2**: Okay, got it working with this code. A special thanks to [Xufox](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4642212/xufox) and [Rimon Habib](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1412503/rimon-habib) for all your help:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

  /* Schedule */

  dateStr2 = new Date(2016, 12, 03);

  last = "lesson";
  lesson = 71; //Lesson you want to start on minus 1
  test = 13; //Test you want to start on minus 1
  inv = 7; //Investigation you want to start on minus 1

  function m10 () {  if ( lesson % 10 == 0) {  return true;  } else {  return false; }  }

  function m10M1 () {  if ( ( (lesson % 10) - 1) == 0 && last == "inv" ) {  return true;  } else {  return false; }  }

  function m5 () {  if ( lesson % 5 == 0) {  return true;  } else {  return false; }  }

  function pMath1 () {  
    if ( m10M1() ) { //Check if Lesson is x1 (e.g. 81) and minus 1 from it
      last = "lesson";
      return "Lesson " + lesson;

    } else if ( m10() == false && last !== "test") { //Add Lesson

      lesson++;
      last = "lesson";
      return "Lesson " + lesson;

    } else if ( m5() == true && last !== "test") { //Add Test

      test++;
      last = "test";
      return "Test " + test;

    } else if ( m10() == true && last == "test") { //Add Inv

      inv++;
      lesson++;
      last = "inv";
      return "Inv " + inv;

    } else {
      console.log("pMath1 doesn't work");
    }
  }


  function pMath2 () {  
    if ( m10M1() ) { //Check if Lesson is x1 (e.g. 81) and minus 1 from it

      last = "lesson";
      return "Lesson " + lesson;

    }else if ( m10() == false ) { //Add Lesson

      lesson++;
      last = "lesson";
      return "Lesson " + lesson;

    } else if ( m5() == true && last !== "test") { //Add Test

      test++;
      last = "test";
      return "Test " + test;

    } else if ( m10() == true && last == "test") { //Add Inv

      inv++;
      lesson++;
      last = "inv";
      return "Inv " + inv;

    } else {
      console.log("pMath2 doesn't work");
    }
  }

  $(".view-id-school .single-day td:gt(6)").each(function () {

    var datePrep = $(this).attr("data-date");
    var dateSplit = datePrep.split("-");
    var dateStr = new Date(dateSplit[0], dateSplit[1], dateSplit[2]);

    var classN = $(this).attr("headers");

    if ( classN == "Monday" || classN == "Wednesday" || classN == "Friday") {

      $(this).removeClass("no-entry");

      var mathC = "M: " + pMath1 () + ", " + pMath2 ();

    } else if (classN == "Tuesday" || classN == "Thursday") {

      $(this).removeClass("no-entry");

      var mathC = "M: " + pMath1 ();

    } else {
      mathC = "";
    };

    content = mathC;  

    if ( dateStr > dateStr2 ) {
      $(this).find(".inner").empty().append('<div class="calendar monthview"><div class="views-field views-field-title"><span class="field-content">' + content + '</span></div><div class="cutoff" /></div></div></div>');
    }

    console.log("Last: " + last + " <br /> Lesson: " + lesson + " <br /> inv: " + inv + " <br /> test: " + test + " <br /> " + "Content: " + content);
  });


});
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: why are you defining functions inside the `.each` loop? Have you ever heard about reusable code?

Comment: The first flaw that I noticed in your logic: `lesson` is never going to be updated. `lesson` starts out with `72` and _could_ increase by 1 within `pMath1` and `pMath2` under the condition that (at least) `m10` returns `false` (corresponding to all the `m10() == false` checks). However, `m10` will only return `false` if `lesson % 10` returns `0`, which it never does (`lesson % 10` is `2`). The second thing: `m10 == false` in `m5` should be `m10() == false`. You need to rethink your logic.

Comment: Try introducing code standards into your work and format your code properly. It's a huge mess right now. I bet you can't even notice, that `m10 == false` inside `function m5()` is an obvious typo, returning `false` and making the whole function return `false`.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OKay, The basic thing about functions and return statement is, if you call return at any point in a function, any code remains of that function after return statement is not going to execute;

So, for pMath1 function, initial value of inv = 8;

and if you notice the pMath1() function,

```
function pMath1 () {  

  if ( m10() == false && m5() == false && last !== test) {

    return "Lesson " + lesson; // code execution stops here as return called
    lesson++; // lesson value is not gonna increment
    last = "lesson"; // neither last value will update

  } else if ( m10() == false && m5() == true) {

    return "Test " + test; // again, code execution stops here
    test++; // test value will not increment
    last = "test"; // neither this will be executed

  } else if ( m10() == true ) {

    return "Inv " + inv; // and here is our inv variable, it was 8, we are returning 8, not giving chance inv to increase as stated line below 
    inv++;
    last = "inv";

  } else {
    console.log("pMath1 doesn't work");
  }
}
```

so, if you follow my comments, you will get the idea what to do, however, I am adjusting the pMath1(),

```
function pMath1 () {  

  if ( m10() == false && m5() == false && last !== test) {

    lesson++; // now lesson value will increase
    last = "lesson"; // and this one will also execute

    return "Lesson " + lesson; // and when we are done, we can return and halt execution here; by this time our variables are processed.

  } else if ( m10() == false && m5() == true) {


    test++; 
    last = "test"; 

    return "Test " + test; // same approach again


  } else if ( m10() == true ) {

    inv++;
    last = "inv";

    return "Inv " + inv; // and here is our holy grail, we gave chance inv to increase first, now we are returning its incremented value. it will be no longer stick with 8.

  } else {
    console.log("pMath1 doesn't work");
  }
}
```

Okay, now our inv variable should not stick with 8, as we know how where to use return, you can try the same thing at pMath2() as it has same mistake. have fun with it :)

Comment: Its not about in which line you are writing which code, its more like, which statement/operator you are using. number are moving 1 line up doesn't mean that variable value will decrease. initial value for inv was 8, and after that, you always used inv++ (which is operator for adding 1 with current value), but you didn't use anywhere inv-- or simply you didnt subtract inv value anywhere, so, there is no reason that value of inv will be less than 8, it will be either 8 or more always.
whole point is,return is a special operator for functions which is used to stop executing code when its called

Comment: ++i wont decrease value either, there is a small difference between i++ and ++i but both does the same work, which increments value. if you want to decrease value, you need to use i-- or --i

Those are actually fundamentals of programming. I would recommend to have some quick reading on C to know programming fundamentals if you have to carry on work with those stuff

Thanks.